# Xceed DataGrid: Filtering Details

Tags: wpf, filter, datagrid, master-detail, xceed

I've got a Master/Detail DataGrid and I want to filter the details. 
Here's my DataGridCollectionViewSource:

```
            <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="Features" 
                                            Filter="ExampleFilter"
                                            Source="{Binding Path=ItemUnderEdit.Features}"
                                            AutoCreateDetailDescriptions="False" 
                                            AutoCreateItemProperties="False">   
            <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.DetailDescriptions>
                <xcdg:PropertyDetailDescription RelationName="Settings"
                                                AutoCreateDetailDescriptions="False"
                                                AutoCreateItemProperties="False">
                </xcdg:PropertyDetailDescription>
            </xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.DetailDescriptions>
        </xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource>
```

As you can see I'm filtering it with *ExampleFilter*, but this only filters the master. I put a breakpoint and it never sees any details.

I cant add a filter to the Detail Descriptions in the same way. Is there any way to filter the details? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I went up against this problem today - I had a simple filter for both the master and detail sections that gets turned on / off via code. For the master section, it was a simple matter of code like:

```
((DataGridCollectionView)grid.ItemsSource).FilterCriteriaMode = FilterCriteriaMode.None; // Off
((DataGridCollectionView)grid.ItemsSource).FilterCriteriaMode = FilterCriteriaMode.And; // On
((DataGridCollectionView)grid.ItemsSource).Refresh(); // Re-run filter.
```

For the details section, it should have been as simple as the following code (it wasn't though):

```
MyDetailDescription.FilterCriteriaMode = FilterCriteriaMode.None; // Off
MyDetailDescription.FilterCriteriaMode = FilterCriteriaMode.And; // On
```

Turns out, doing that will enable the new filter for any new detail sections that get generated, but not existing ones. New detail sections are generated when the master row is expanded. To get around this it turned out I needed a simple foreach loop such as:

```
foreach (DataGridContext context in grid.GetChildContexts()) {
    ((DataGridCollectionViewBase)(context.Items)).FilterCriteriaMode = PetsDetailDescriptions.FilterCriteriaMode;
}
```

Here's my complete(ish) code for all that:

```
public bool ShowDeleted {
    set {
        if ((grid.ItemsSource != null) && (grid.ItemsSource.GetType() == DataGridCollectionView));
            DataGridCollectionView v = ((DataGridCollectionView)(grid.ItemsSource));
            if (value) {
                v.FilterCriteriaMode = FilterCriteriaMode.None;
                MyDetailDescription.FilterCriteriaMode = FilterCriteriaMode.None;
            }
            else {
                v.FilterCriteriaMode = FilterCriteriaMode.And;
                MyDetailDescription.FilterCriteriaMode = FilterCriteriaMode.And;
            }

            foreach (DataGridContext context in grid.GetChildContexts()) {
                ((DataGridCollectionViewBase)(context.Items)).FilterCriteriaMode = PetsDetailDescriptions.FilterCriteriaMode;
            }
            v.Refresh();
        }

    }
}
```

I'm using that in-conjunction with a simple predefined filter criterion in the XAML. IE:

```
        <g:DataGridItemProperty Name="IsDeleted"
                                DataType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}">
            <g:DataGridItemProperty.FilterCriterion>
                <g:EqualToFilterCriterion>
                    <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                </g:EqualToFilterCriterion>
            </g:DataGridItemProperty.FilterCriterion>
        </g:DataGridItemProperty>
```

I recommend using the Xaml FilterCriterions, because if you absolutely need the Filter event, it's going to get a bit more messy. For that route, you need to do the following steps:

1. Tap into the event when a new child DataGridContext is added to the control.
2. Add a predicate reference to the context.Items.Filter property (in the code state, this is a property expecting predicate, not an event).
3. Write your filter code in the predicate function.

I'm not 100% sure how to achieve #1 above (as I didn't need to go that route). However, a good place to possible start is the DetailsExpanding and DetailsExpanded events of the DataGridControl. For the expanding, I'm not sure if the child DataGridContext exists yet (as there is an option to cancel the expanding). So you might have to wait until after the expanded event.

I hope this helps point you in the right direction.